# ASP MVC 4 JsonResult how to use ISO 8601 dates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have just installed ASP MVC 4 and my JSON dates are still coming back in the old format `{"timestamp":"\/Date(1348070400000)\/"}`.

I was [under the impression](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx) that they should be coming back in the format `2012-02-18T00:54:06.8447642Z` without me doing anything.

> Note: JSON.NET is now an integral part of ASP.NET Web API so you can
>   just us it out of the box.

My controller looks something like this

```
public JsonResult Test()
{
    return Json(new {timestamp = DateTime.Now()}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How can I get this to work? Do I need to make a change in my Global.asax.cs or Web.config?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I was under the impression that they should be coming back in the
>   format 2012-02-18T00:54:06.8447642Z without me doing anything.

That's true only for ASP.NET Web API (ApiControllers). But standard ASP.NET MVC controller actions returning JsonResults still use the `JavaScriptSerializer`. So if you want to use ISO 8601 dates you could swap this serializer by JSON.NET by writing a [custom action result](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx). Just add the proper converter to the settings used by the serializer:

```
SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
```

You might be asking why they didn't implement JSON.NET for standard controllers. I guess it's for compatibility reasons as that would be an important breaking change. But I would probably have made JSON.NET the default serializer with a fallback option for those upgrading their existing applications.

Comment: Hi, I have a ActionResult returning a PartialView with a model and I want the model to be serialized using the JsonNetResult class... any clue? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to return JSON then instead of returning a PartialView from your action you should return a custom ActionResult which is using JSON.NET as serializer - the JsonNetResult for example.