# How to split list of values in a jQuery datatable?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, split, datatable

I have a datatable that includes a column that has a list of values. For example, Activity Phase Dates has a list of comma-separated dates. I cannot use `render: function (data) { return moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY");` because a list of dates is not a valid date.

How can I split this list of dates to then apply `render: function (data) { return moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY");`? I have tried split(','), but it does not work. Most likely because this list of values is not a string. I also tried replace(',', ' '), but also did not work for probably the same reason.

Actions:

```
    public JsonResult LoadApplications()
    {
        return Json(new { data = GetApplications("") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private IEnumerable GetApplications(string keyword)
    {
        var applications = from a in _db.Applications
                           where a.AppNumber.ToString().Contains(keyword)
                               || a.NonCityMortgageDate.ToString().Contains(keyword)
                               || a.ApplicationActivityPhas.Any(d => d.ActivityPhaseDate.ToString().Contains(keyword))
                           select new
                           {
                               a.AppNumber, a.NonCityMortgageDate, 
                               ActivityPhaseDates = a.ApplicationActivityPhas.Select(d => d.ActivityPhaseDate).ToList(),
                               a.Id
                           };

        return applications;
    }
```

DataTable:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ApplicationDataTable").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadApplications", "Application")',
                datatype: "json",
                type: "GET"
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "AppNumber",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var applicationDetails = '@Url.Action("Details", "Application")/' + row.Id;
                        return '<a href=\"' + applicationDetails + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "NonCityMortgageDate",
                    type: "date",
                    render: function (data) {
                        if (data != null) {
                            return moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
                        }
                        else {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: "ActivityPhaseDates",
                    type: "date",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
                    }
                },
                { data: "Id" }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Index:

```
    <div class="pt-2">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="ApplicationDataTable">
            <thead class="table-info">
                <tr>
                    <th>Application Number</th>
                    <th>Non City Mortgage Date</th>
                    <th>Activity Phase Dates</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: *a list of comma-separated dates* - so it's a string?  So outputs the "raw" data if you did `render: function(data) { return data; }`?  (ie incorrectly formatted dates, separated by a comma)  - If so, split, then format each string.

Comment: Something like `data.split(",").map((d) => moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY")).join(", ")`

Comment: I tried the following, but the datatable says "Loading..." => {
                        data: "ActivityPhaseDates",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return data.split(",").map((d) => moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY")).join(", ");
                        }
                    },

Comment: It's not easy to try giving an answer without seeing how data looks like. String? Array? Can you post an example of what you get from your ajax call for the specified column?

Comment: If I just have `{ data: "ActivityPhaseDates" }` then the output for this column in the datatable is : /Date(1648447200000)/,/Date(1648533600000)/,/Date(1648620000000)/,/Date(1648533600000)/,/Date(1648533600000)/,/Date(1648533600000)/. The output as shown in Inspect is: "ActivityPhaseDates":["\/Date(1648447200000)\/","\/Date(1648533600000)\/","\/Date(1648620000000)\/","\/Date(1648533600000)\/","\/Date(1648533600000)\/","\/Date(1648533600000)\/"],

Comment: These look like dates from the default json serializer which does a *really* bad job of proviing dates.  The usual solution is to replace the json serializer (eg with the Newtonsoft serialiser), then your dates come out in something usable ie change it in your asp.net.  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12506911/2181514) provides a link to the solution [custom action result](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net).   Once you set it up with an ActionFilter, you can forget all about it and all your JsonResult action results will have the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a solution:

```
{
    data: "ActivityPhaseDates",
    render: function (data) {
        var activityPhaseDates = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            activityPhaseDates += moment(data[i]).format("MM/DD/YYYY") + " ";
        }
        return activityPhaseDates;
    }
}
```

The output is:

03/14/2022 03/31/2022 03/31/2022 03/31/2022 03/31/2022